# Rspec testing of flash messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am having issues getting my specs to work with the following:

Inside of my IntegrationController:

```
def check_jira_url
    if params[:user][:jira_url] == ""
      flash[:error] = "Please enter your JIRA application URL. It should start with http:// or https://"
      render check_jira_group_plan_path
    elsif params[:user][:jira_url][0,4] != "http"
      flash[:error] = "Bad JIRA path. Please correct your JIRA application URL. It should start with http:// or https://"
      render check_jira_group_plan_path
    else
      session[:jira_url] = params[:user][:jira_url]
      users = User.where(:jira_url => session[:jira_url])
      if users.count > 0
        current_user.jira_url = session[:jira_url]
        current_user.save
        redirect_to new_auth_jira_path
      else
        redirect_to jira_integration_path(:full_setup => true)
      end
    end
  end
```

The spec I am writing:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe IntegrationController do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, :without_callbacks, :email => 'test@c.com') }

  describe 'check jira url' do
    before { sign_in_user(user) }
    it 'flashes error message for blank url' do
      post :check_jira_url, {:jira_url => ''}
      expect(flash[:error]).to be_present
      response.should render_template(:action=> 'check_jira_group_plan')
    end
  end
end
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
expected present? to return true, got false
./spec/controllers/integration_controler_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try `expect(subject.request.flash[:error]).to be_present` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, you're checking whether the URL is an empty string:

```
if params[:user][:jira_url] == ""
```

But in your spec, you're sending a POST like this:

```
post :check_jira_url, {:jira_url => ''}
```

The params in your controller look something like `{:jira_url => ''}` rather than `{:user => {:jira_url => ''}}` which your controller would expect.

So the line in your spec should look like:

```
post :check_jira_url, {:user => {:jira_url => ''}}
```